# How can one change the arrow shaft thickness globally in a TikZ picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

How can one change the thickness of *all* arrow shafts in a TikZ picture, e.g., in the following grossly simplified, stripped-down version of the example https://texample.net/tikz/examples/homotopy/?

As the commented code indicates, I tried in each of two places to specify the thickness, but neither seems to have any effect.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
%\tikzstyle{arrow}=[ultra thick] % no effect here ??
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
%[arrow/.style={ultra thick}] % no effect here, either??
  \node  (x1) at (6,0)  {$\bullet$};
  \node  (x0) at (9,4)  {$\bullet$};
  \node (R) at (2,4){$\bullet$};
  \draw[->] ($(R.west)+(-20pt,0)$) to[out=-180,in=240] ++(0,2)
    to [out=60,in=120]node[above,midway]{}(x0);
  \draw[->] ($(R.north)+(0,10pt)$) to [out=60,in=120]
    node[above,midway]{} ++(4.5,-1);
  \draw[->] ($(R.east)+(20pt,0)$)  to [out=0,in=140]
    node[right,midway]{}(x1);
  \draw[->] ($(R.south)+(0,-20pt)$)  to [out=-85,in=-30]
    node[below,midway]{}++(7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As indicated below, there is no predefined `arrow` style, so creating one without using it has no effect. There is an `every path` style, but that would change all none-arrow paths as well, so probably not useful for you, I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

Use `arrows.meta` library and declare a global arrow style.

[image: global arrow size]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[scale=3]}]
  \node  (x1) at (6,0)  {$\bullet$};
  \node  (x0) at (9,4)  {$\bullet$};  
  \node (R) at (2,4){$\bullet$};
  \draw[->] ($(R.west)+(-20pt,0)$) to[out=-180,in=240] ++(0,2)
    to [out=60,in=120]node[above,midway]{}(x0); 
  \draw[->] ($(R.north)+(0,10pt)$) to [out=60,in=120]
    node[above,midway]{} ++(4.5,-1); 
  \draw[->] ($(R.east)+(20pt,0)$)  to [out=0,in=140]
    node[right,midway]{}(x1); 
  \draw[->] ($(R.south)+(0,-20pt)$)  to [out=-85,in=-30]
    node[below,midway]{}++(7,0);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

If you want to create a custom style, you have to also use it. Like below with `arr` style. And the use of `tikzstyle` is deprecated now, you should use `tikzset`.

[image: global arrow size 2]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}

\tikzset{arr/.style={ultra thick,->,>={Stealth[scale=1.5]}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node  (x1) at (6,0)  {$\bullet$};
  \node  (x0) at (9,4)  {$\bullet$};  
  \node (R) at (2,4){$\bullet$};
  \draw[arr] ($(R.west)+(-20pt,0)$) to[out=-180,in=240] ++(0,2)
    to [out=60,in=120]node[above,midway]{}(x0); 
  \draw[arr] ($(R.north)+(0,10pt)$) to [out=60,in=120]
    node[above,midway]{} ++(4.5,-1); 
  \draw[arr] ($(R.east)+(20pt,0)$)  to [out=0,in=140]
    node[right,midway]{}(x1); 
  \draw[arr] ($(R.south)+(0,-20pt)$)  to [out=-85,in=-30]
    node[below,midway]{}++(7,0);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Using `[>={Stealth[scale=3]}]` magnifies the arrow heads. That's not what I asked to do! I asked about the width of the arrow *shafts*. (2) What' wrong with the two (commented-out) things I tried -- why don't they work?

Comment: In your code, you declare a tikz style `arrow` and you don't use it further. So it's not effective. I edited my answer to let eyou know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could redefine `->`, though whether that has unintended consequences I don't know, so do test it. This may be a bad idea.

Obviously if you want the same thing for `<-` and `<->` as well, you'll need  to redefine those as well.

```
\tikzset{->/.style={-Latex, ultra thick}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc} 
\tikzset{->/.style={-Latex, ultra thick}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \node  (x1) at (6,0)  {$\bullet$};
  \node  (x0) at (9,4)  {$\bullet$};  
  \node (R) at (2,4){$\bullet$};
  \draw[->] ($(R.west)+(-20pt,0)$) to[out=-180,in=240] ++(0,2)
    to [out=60,in=120]node[above,midway]{}(x0); 
  \draw[->] ($(R.north)+(0,10pt)$) to [out=60,in=120]
    node[above,midway]{} ++(4.5,-1); 
  \draw[->] ($(R.east)+(20pt,0)$)  to [out=0,in=140]
    node[right,midway]{}(x1); 
  \draw[->] ($(R.south)+(0,-20pt)$)  to [out=-85,in=-30]
    node[below,midway]{}++(7,0);    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would recommend SebGlav's method over this.